# Parse BinaryTree with (Read a, Show a)

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am having a little trouble on how to start this problem. I am supposed to parse a string representation of a binary tree and check whether the contents of a leaf have valid letters and if they do then create the tree else return "" for failed parsing all without deriving  (Show,Read)

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf a | Branch (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a) deriving Show


data letters = A | B | C | D | E | F | G deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Bounded, Read)

lett = [(A)..(G)]
str = "Branch (Leaf A) (Branch (Branch (Leaf A) (Leaf C)) (Leaf D))"

parse:: (Read a, Show a) => [a] -> String ->  BinaryTree  a
```

Using a typical parser library I could use  something along the lines of

```
parseTree = do{item; symb "Leaf"; x <- string; return Leaf (read x)} +++ {item; symb "Branch"; item;x <- parseTree; item; item; y <- parseTree; item; return (Branch x y)}
```

The type constraint of  (Read a, Show a) confuses me as I am unsure how I would handle the case of going through a leaf or branch.

Comment: You can use `deriving (Show, Read)` in your `data BinaryTree`, and thne it will make a parser itself.

Comment: There is something not entirely correct with the function code, it should be `return (Branch x y)` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Willem says, you can derive `Read` to get this function for free:

```hs
data Letter = A | B | C | D | E | F | G
  deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Bounded, Read)

data BinaryTree a = Leaf a | Branch (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

t :: BinaryTree Letter
t = Branch (Leaf A) (Branch (Branch (Leaf A) (Leaf C)) (Leaf D))
```

Trying this:

```hs
λ> t == read (show t)
True
```

> create the tree else return "" for failed parsing all without `deriving (Show, Read)`.
>
> ```hs
> parseTree = do{ item; symb "Leaf"; ... +++ ... }
> ```

I'm not sure what "" means in the context of reading a binary tree from a string: According to your definition of binary tree, trees cannot be empty, since even `Leaf` contains at least one letter. So maybe you're looking for a function `String -> Maybe (BinaryTree Letter)`.

Since your reluctance to use derived `Show` and `Read` instances, this must be an exercise in writing a parser. You could structure a recursive-descent parser in the following way:

```hs
parseLetter :: String -> Maybe (Letter, String)
parseLetter s = ...

parseTree :: String -> Maybe (BinaryTree Letter, String)
parseTree s
  | "Leaf " `isPrefixOf` s = ...
  | "Branch " `isPrefixOf` s = ...
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

Here the `(..., String)` is the left-over of the string being parsed that isn't consumed by a sub-parser. E.g. in parsing `Branch (Leaf A) (Leaf B)`, when `parseLetter` has parsed `A`, it may return `(A, ") (Leaf B)")` for its caller.

Note, however, that getting something of comparable quality to `deriving Read` requires being pretty flexible with regards to whitespace and parentheses:

```
λ> read "Branch ( Leaf A)(  Branch (  Leaf B )   ((Leaf C) )   ) " :: BinaryTree Letter
Branch (Leaf A) (Branch (Leaf B) (Leaf C))
```

> I am unsure how I would handle the case of going through a leaf or branch

Going through a leaf means parsing a single letter.

Going through a branch means calling upon the parser recursively.

You may want to use a more efficient and ergonomic parsing library, like [what `Text.Read` exposes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-Read.html) (it even contains an example of reading a tree type), or you might want to use a parser combinator framework like [Megaparsec](https://markkarpov.com/megaparsec/megaparsec.html) or [ReadP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#t:ReadP).